# Is there a possible way to send and receive objects (with proto) between client and server side with object being defined client-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

My application creates objects with prototypes client-side using JavaScript and also uses jQuery. I need to send objects to the server (which is running Node.js) so that it can be sent to other client-side pages.

Comment: So you don't need to use these objects (with their prototpes) in server code? Just store them and revive them on the client later?

Comment: Yes. Its an encryption system and I need to send public keys to be stored and sent to other clients.

Comment: If it's just one type, send the data and construct the object from that data when you get it later.

Comment: you are looking for (de)serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have an object with methods on the client:

```js
class Rect {
  constructor(top, left, width, height) {
    this.top = top;
    this.left = left;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }

  get right() {
    return this.left+this.width;
  }

  get bottom() {
    return this.top+this.height;
  }
}
```

And you only need to get the `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` on the server.

If you only need the raw data then there is nothing that needs to be done. Just send the object using Fetch or your favorite XHR service. The values will show in an object on the server and you can use it.

But if you need to use the object methods on the server then you will need to include the above code on both the client and the server. Also the server will need to convert the raw object back into the class `Rect` again to be able to call `bottom` and `right.